# Nested Snippets

Tags: yasnippet

Let's say that I have the following snippet in Emacs:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: frac
# key: frac
# --
\frac{${1:numerator}}{${2:denominator}}$0
```

My problem is that when I write a snippet inside this snippet and press tab then the snippet is not expanding but the cursor is moving to the next placeholder.

How can I make it to first expand the snippet and then, with the next tab ro move, to the next placeholder?

Comment: Could you perhaps show also the second snippet inside the first?

Comment: @Drew There is not one specifically. Also the one I wrote is just an example. Every time I write a snippet and I want to nest one more then the tab moves the cursor without expanding first the second snippet.

Answer (score 4):

From [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9557579/2580133), we see that:

> `yas-triggers-in-field` is a variable defined in `yasnippet.el`.
>
> Its value is `t`
>
> Original value was `nil`
>
> Documentation:
>
> If non-nil, allow stacked expansions (snippets inside snippets).
>
> Otherwise `yas-next-field-or-maybe-expand` just moves on to the
>   next field
>
> You can customize this variable.

So the solution to allow nested templates is:

```el
(setq yas-triggers-in-field t)
```